# execute flush javascript before finishing

Tags: javascript

i've written a function which waits x milliseconds before executing another function. now i have problem with that it won't execute any change until it finishes.

```
this.changeColor('#99FFCC');
this.pausecomp(this, 'changeColor','#FFFFFF', 1000);

changeColor = function (color)
{
    this.inputElem.style.backgroundColor = color;
};


pausecomp = function (element, meth, argument, ms)
{
    ms += new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < ms) {}
    element[meth](argument);
}
```

this script will execute as expected but it won't change color until it finishes all. so firt color won't be displayed for 500ms ...

i can't use setTimeout()

my main goal is to blink textbox background so if there's a way to do this with css or any other please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: `i can't use setTimeout()` this is your main problem. What could possibly hinder you from using it?

Comment: This is probably the most horrible thing you can do to ECMAscript.. that is calling `while` to block/freeze execution. I guarantee there is a better solution for your problem.

Comment: **Do** call setTimeout(). That's the standard way to let the browser update the screen.

Comment: Or use `_.delay()` from Underscore.js… Although it also defers to `setTimeout()`. =) Anyway, maybe the problem with using `setTimeout` is that `this` changes in callback? That's fixable.

Comment: @jAndy It may use `while` somewhere underneath, but does `setTimeout()` really block? I thought its point was the opposite.

Comment: setTimeout() sets my this variable to window ... i need instance of the object in use

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
changeColor(this, '#99FFCC');
pausecomp(this, 'changeColor','#FFFFFF', 1000);

changeColor = function (element, color)
{
    element.inputElem.style.backgroundColor = color;
};


pausecomp = function (element, meth, argument, ms)
{
    setTimeout(function() {element[meth](argument); }, ms);
}
```

Comment: Although, `changeColor` was never added as a method of this. So you're gonna have to figure that one out

Comment: @Mazmart This is a common obstacle while learning javascript. Try to get it straight from the start and you'll run into a lot less problems later on. Blocking the browser using a while loop is really horrible  as jAndy put quit correctly.